# Is flutter only good for UI-related stuff?

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, flutter-layout, mobile-development

I'm a complete beginner in Flutter.
I was wondering whether Flutter is only meant for Front-end UI stuff or can it be used for little more advanced stuff. Maybe something like sockets??

Answer (score 2):

Flutter is a mobile UI framework for [Dart](https://dart.dev/) Programming Language. Therefore yes, [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) is just for UI related work.

The good thing is that it is based on the [Dart Language](https://dart.dev/), which has the possibility to do more than just UI work. It is capable of everything that you would expect in any other programming language. So Sockets should be no issue.

An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51213832/3690032).

Answer (score 1):

Not only for Front-end but also for the backend.

In fact, you could use Dart to build a Http server,
and there are packages on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/http_server)

As you could use NodeJS to do a lot of things, as same as Dart here,
it depends on what kinds of you want to achieve.

So, you've talked about socket, there are also kinds of packages there on pub.dev.

Checked the packages of the socket on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages?q=socket), hope this helps.